# How to produce ad-hoc Kafka messages on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

Is there an easy way to produce some ad-hoc Kafka messages without setting up any programming environment?

Answer (score -2):

Navigate to your `bin/windows` directory and use one of following commands.

**Manually add messages one by one**

```
./kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic test
>value1
>value2
```

**Manually add messages with keys one by one**

```
> ./kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic test --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=;"
>key1;value1
>key2;value2
```

Just add `parse.key` and `key.separator` properties. The example uses `;` but there is nothing special about it, one can use any other character.

**Automatically add multiple messages with keys**

```
1..1000 | %{"Key$_;Message$_"} | Write-Output | ./kafka-console-producer.bat --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=;" --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic test
```

The command adds 1000 messages with keys using simple PowerShell script.

Comment: Can you show the complete directory? "bin/windows" doesn't exist! We are talking about how to send messages... Can you show the links with the .bat solution?

Comment: As a prerequisite you need to download the kafka binary package. In there you will find the mentioned batch files.